# "there's a normally and we're using `two's` complement arithmetic inside our machine"

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

I was watching an educational lecture about programming where the instructor has said:

> So, that means that they can get larger. Meaning, there's a normally and we're using `two's` complement arithmetic inside our machine.

Why he has added an `'s` for property after `there's a normally and we're using` it doesn't make sense for me!

Comment: As Yvon mentioned in a comment, *two's complement* is the name of a kind of arithmetic.

Comment: The phrase "there's a normally" doesn't mean anything. Either the instructor misspoke or there's an error in the transcription. More likely the latter because it's not even close to meaningful in its current state.

Comment: If you provide a link to the video and tell us the time at which this was said, we can tell you what the words were.

Answer (score 1):

“Two’s Complement” is the formal name of a method of encoding signed integers in binary.  It contrasts with the older “One’s Complement” and “Sign and Magnitude” (sometimes written “Signed Magnitude”) methods. The apostrophes are part of the names.

“there’s a normally” is presumably a transcription error, but I’d need the video link to figure out what was actually said.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the whole thing really doesn't make much sense to me. Since I'm not sure what context he was speaking in, I don't even know what he is talking about. Because you were watching a video, I will assume that what you were reading were automated subtitles. If I am correct, then you can rest assured that many times automated subtitles make mistakes (I have noticed that MANY times). Yet, since I cannot know for sure, here is a quote from [GrammarBook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp):

> Single-digit numbers are usually spelled out, but when they aren't, you are just as likely to see 2s and 3s as 2's and 3's. With double digits and above, many (but not everyone) regard the apostrophe as superfluous: I scored in the high 90s.

If you can give more information, people may be better equipped to give you a specific answer.

Comment: Here's the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for Two's complement. It is a mathematical operation on binary numbers, and it is used in programming. You also have `One's complement` which is a similar thing.